# How do I carry old ID keys forward into a new database structure?

Tags: sql, database, etl, database-migration

Given a project I'm working on, we have an old database structure we're migrating data from into a new database structure, and we need to preserve the old keys for a few tables for backwards compatibility with some existing application functionality.

Currently, there are two approaches we are considering for addressing this need:

1. Create an extra nullable field for each table and insert the old key into that new field
2. Create companion table(s) that contain the old and new key mappings

Note: new data will not generate old ID keys, so in approach #1, eventually the nullable field will contain nulls over time for new records.

- Which approach is better for a cleaner database design, and data management long-term?
- Do you see any issues with either approach, and if so, what issues?
- Is there a #3 approach that I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: Depending on your exact back comparability requirements I will go either with your #1 (no pun intended) or with 
`#3`: Create **not** nullable column with old keys and in the new system place new IDs there in addition to their own column.

Answer (score 0):

You mention sql, but is it SQL-Server?

if SQL-Server, look into [SET INSERT_IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).  This allows you to explicitly insert values for the auto-increment columns vs being in a protected mode for that column.

However, I believe that if you explicitly include the PK in the insert statement with its value, it will respect that and save the original key in the original column you are hoping to retain without having to force yet another column for backward compatibility purposes.